# Is there a way to generate PAT in Azure B2C

Tags: c#, node.js, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-msal

I have a api's which are exposed to users, and i have added B2C authentication in Middleware.

asking customers to login everytime & ask to get token is not looking a great idea,

Gone through documents about refresh token, but refresh tokens max lifetime is 3 months.

Just like Azure Functions can we generate a PAT for B2C app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When refresh token expires you will fall back to cookie based authentication at AAD B2C.

You can create a persistent cookie with length of many years using “keep me signed in”.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#enable-keep-me-signed-in-kmsi